# mysql работа с Events

Tags: mysql

Есть event которые вызывает хранимую процедуру.Можно ли передать параметры в евент который в свою очередь передаст их в процедуру?

Answer (score 1):

Параметры в эвент передать нельзя - аргумент эвента является литералом. Но можно заранее поместить требуемое значение в такое место, откуда ХП его сможет взять - например, в служебную таблицу или глобальную переменную.